# After upgrading corephp to laravel behind aws ELB application cannot login, keep on asking login page

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

We have migrated a core php application to laravel behind AWS ELB(Prod1, Prod2 and RDS).
Before in core php everything works fine, but comes to laravel Prod1 with single instances it is working fine as expected but with adding 2 instances(prod1, prod2) to the Load Balancer (ELB) is not working. It's keep on asking login page even after providing the login credentials for the first 2 or 3 times and for the 4th time it is loggin in.sometimes this count vary from 1-4.

Please help us.

Comment: Not easy to debut code we don't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to enable sticky sessions on your load balancer. The problem lies in that your user is bouncing to a different server and the other server does not have the session for the user.

Check out the AWS docs here in session stickiness. The setting by has to be tweaked at the load balancer level in AWS

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html